# Is there a way to initialize a 3D array like this in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to initialize memory in c++ with chain of pointers.But when I tried something different the code crashed.I don't understand why won't this work.
Please someone could explain this.
In the main() I write something like,

```
double ***dArr = NULL;
dArr = new double**[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    arr[i] = new double*[5]);
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = new double[5]);
    }
}
//But if I do this it crashes
typedef double*** D;
D arr;
arr = *(new D[5]); 
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    arr[i] = **(new D[5]);    //why cant I do this?Compiler is OK with this but asserts.
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = ***(new D[5]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `std::vector<>`. It's much more convenient than messing with pointers.

Comment: And if you really insist on not using the stdlib but instead writing your own buggy imitations for no apparent reason... provide a complete, self-contained, _accurate_ example - not "I write something like" - and if you have to say something like "Compiler is OK with this but asserts", then you can surely copy and paste the exact error message you were trying to paraphrase.

Comment: why would you want to write such a mess when you can initialize a 3D array with `my_3d_monsterType x = { {{1},{2},{3}}, {{4},{5},{6}},{{7},{8},{9}}};` where `my_3d_monsterType` is an appropriate alias for nested `std::array`s or `std::vector`s? Btw better use a flat array

Comment: @Msalters Yeah, pointers get extremely messy when doing multi-dimensional arrays. They're only worth it for 1-dimensional ones.

Comment: @underscore_d..OK I have written "I write something like" because I was trying this out and it didnot work.And I am unable to understand why cant I do like this.Next the  message that I get is segmentation fault and It gives an error message..Access violation reading location 0XCDCDCDC.

Comment: This sounds like a great time to start learning how to use a debugger to step through your code, observe how variables change and from/to what, and backtrace from crashes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet you are allocating different types

```
double ***dArr = NULL;
dArr = new double**[5];
// ...     ^^^^^^^^
    arr[i] = new double*[5]);
   // ...        ^^^^^^^   ^ Typo? Using () you'd initialize those pointers
       arr[i][j] = new double[5]);
       // ...          ^^^^^^   ^ Again?
```

But in the second one, you are instructing the compiler to always allocate an array of 5 `double ***` and dereference multiple times uninitialized memory.

```
typedef double*** D;
D arr;
arr = *(new D[5]);
// ...  ^^^^^^^^
    arr[i] = **(new D[5]);
    // ...      ^^^^^^^^
        arr[i][j] = ***(new D[5]);
        // ...          ^^^^^^^^
```

Save yourself a lot of troubles and use a `std::array` or a `std::vector`

```
// With fixed size known at compile time
std::array<std::array<std::array<double, 5>, 5>, 5> arr;

// Or dynamically allocated
using vec2d = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;
std::vector<vec2d> = darr(5, vec2d(5, std::vector<double>(5)));
```

Later you could experiment with a `class` wrapping a 1D `vector` and proper indices mapping.